# Issue on Passing param to Template as Variable in Html Using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, templates, vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vue js to implement template system, its completely dynamic.

So i need to pass attributes and variables to template and each template has different values.

I done on passing attributes, but issue on passing value of a variable.

Here,

**My HTML** :

```
      <div v-for="product in productsList">
                  <block v-if="column == 4 || column > 4"
                      :listAlign="showList ? 'left' : 'center'"
                      :product_name = product.name
                      :showAction="showAction"
                      :block_class="showList ? 'col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12' : 'col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'">
                  </block>
      </div>
```

Here, i have to pass the value of 1. **product_name**, 2. **product_price**, 3. **showAction**

Also the **Class** and **Align** attributes are passed successfully.

**My Template** :

```
    <template v-if="showTemplate" id="campaignBlock">
        <div :class="block_class" :align="listAlign">
             <p>@{{ product_name }}</p>
             <p>Price : @{{ product_price }}</p>
             <input v-show="showAction" type="button" @click="alt()" class="btn btn-default
                    " value="Action">
        </div>
   </template>
```

**My VueJS** :

```
Vue.component('block', {
template: '#campaignBlock',
props: ['block_class', 'align', 'listAlign','showAction', 'product_name','product_name'],
data: function () {
    return {
        n: 0,
        nb: 1,
        column: 2,
        showPrice: false,
        showAction: true,
        showList: false,
        listAlign: 'left'
    }
   }
 });
```

I only having trouble with passing variables to template.

Is this concept is possible ?

Or any other solution for this issue ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly error you are getting. I have corrected few mistakes, check below:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="showTemplate" id="campaignBlock">
    <div :class="{'col-md-12' : block_class_var}" :align="listAlign">
         <p>{{ product_name }}</p>
         <p>Price : {{ product_price }}</p>
         <input v-show="showAction" type="button" @click="alt()" class="btn btn-default
                " value="Action">
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) is the documentation of using dynamic class in vueJs.

Comment: Its said, product_name & product_price is not defined.

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan product_price is not there in the props list also, neither it is passed in the component.

Comment: This also provide the same.
I'm using laravel so i use '@' at prefix.